# Django Many to Many Field

Tags: django

Whenever I create a new `PreDefinedSet` it grabs all the equipment that I've added in my database.

Question is how do I make it blank and is it possible to edit what's inside a many to many field?

My goal is to make a class where in it is a list of equipment which can be predefined by the users.

Here are my models:

```
class Equipment(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

class PreDefinedSet(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    Equipments = models.ManyToManyField(Equipment)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it grabs all..."?

Answer (score 0):

I think I see what you are trying to do. Your model looks fine - I don't see any reason why a `PreDefinedSet` would have related data added on creation (if you are not doing anything funny there).

```
class Equipment(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

class PreDefinedSet(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    equipments = models.ManyToManyField(Equipment, related_name='sets')
```

Now if you want to manipulate with the data:

```
eq = Equipment.objects.get(name='something')
user_set = PreDefinedSet.objects.create(name='first_set')

user_set.equipments.add(eq)

user_set.equipments.all()  # will return a QuerySet with one Equipment
```

Additionally notice the `related_name` thanks to which you can reverse query, like this:

```
eq.sets.all()  # will return a QuerySet of the sets that tool is in
```

More about how to manipulate M2M fields: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#many-to-many-relationships